# The ipconfig command on other networked computers under same domain/workgroup

Tags: networking, command-line, ipconfig

Does the ipconfig command only work on the workstation that you are physically on or can it be used across a domain/workgroup? Is there a different command that does accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It only works on the current workstation.  You can use the [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) tool to run it on a remote machine:

```
> psexec \\remotecomputer ipconfig /all
```

If you have more than one computer, you can put the computer names in a textfile (eg `computerlist.txt`) and run it like this:

```
> psexec @computerlist.txt ipconfig /all
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who interested in the solution how to get IP config remotely..

I found the best way to obtain IP settings remotely. It can be easily done with Remote IP Configuration utility of AdminToys Suite from http://www.admintoyssuite.com/

It allows you to change network card settings instead of just viewing IP address, mask, DHCP etc.

Hope that helps

Comment: Could you please disclose your affiliation with the product according to the FAQ? Excessive self-promoting is not welcome here